# material-react-table Col span and Row span

Tags: reactjs, material-table

So I am trying to make a colspan on the header of the material react table, but I notice it doesn't change anything at all. It only renders an existing column, here is my try:

```
return (
    <div className="m-2">
      <MaterialReactTable
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        getRowId={(row) => row.phoneNumber}
        initialState={{ showColumnFilters: false }}
        manualFiltering
        manualPagination
        manualSorting
        muiToolbarAlertBannerProps={
          isError
            ? {
                color: "error",
                children: "Error loading data",
              }
            : undefined
        }
        onColumnFiltersChange={setColumnFilters}
        onGlobalFilterChange={setGlobalFilter}
        onPaginationChange={setPagination}
        onSortingChange={setSorting}
        rowCount={rowCount}
        components={{
          Header: (props) => {
            return (
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell rowSpan={2}>Material</TableCell>

                  <TableCell rowSpan={2} align="center">
                    Action
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell align="center">Time</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">Date</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">Time</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">Date</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
            );
          },
          Row: ({ datas }) => {
            return (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>{data.approve}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{data.inTime}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{data.inDate}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{data.outTime}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{data.outDate}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{data.action}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          },
        }}
        state={{
          columnFilters,
          globalFilter,
          isLoading,
          pagination,
          showAlertBanner: isError,
          showProgressBars: isRefetching,
          sorting,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

and here is what its look like:
[image]

Can someone tell me what I am doing? I try to figure it out but nothing changes at all

Comment: why you don't using Data Grid substitute table ?

Comment: never heard about it before.. @JawadFadel as i reseacrh cols grouping only availabe for Datagrid pro Material Ui

Comment: anyhelp on that? or maybe any documentation datagird substitute table that u said? @JawadFadel

Comment: for your problem i use another table easy to use and you have full controller 
Link: https://www.material-react-table.com/

Comment: what do you mean by another table easy? @JawadFadel

Comment: use it the told me it will help u or not

Comment: it works @JawadFadel by reading whole documentation in one night it works as i want, tahnks a lot man